# How to prevent "this webpage has reloaded because it is using significant memory"

Tags: macos, safari, webkit

In OS 11 Big Sur, I often get "**this webpage has reloaded because it is using significant memory**" while watching videos for class in Safari. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? The forced reloading of the webpage causes the video to start the beginning everytime (happening every minute or so of watching). Before the latest update it would only give a prompt that significant memory is in use and I should reload/close the tab but now it reloads automatically and it makes the videos unwatchable, any advice on how to stop this from automatically happening?

Comment: Try using Chrome or Firefox (or any other browser) and see if that solves it. Also please go to [feedbackassistant.apple.com](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com), login in your AppleID, and file a bug report – you'll need the version numbers of macOS & Safari and the URL you're having issues with. HTH